# removing a query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 60 or so old product URLS like this:

http://www.domain.com/page.php?pid=Product Name

I can rewrite the like this.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pid=Product%20Name [NC]

RewriteRule ^page\.php /my/new/url/for/Product_Name [R=301,NE,L]
```

But this leaves the query string on the new url like this

http://www.domain.com/my/new/url/for/Product_Name?pid=Product%20Name

1/ Is there a way to remove the query string?

2/ Do I need to do the same for all 60 products? Fine but just a lot of copy/paste.

Thanks as ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about other params:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pid=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^page\.php /my/new/url/for/%1? [R=301,NE,L]
```

If you want to save other params, use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)pid=([^&]*)&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^page\.php /my/new/url/for/%2?%1%3 [R=301,NE,L,QSA]
```

This will leave a hanging ? when there are no other parameters, or a hanging & when pid is the last param on the list, but these are still valid urls.

Comment: Looks impressive. I'll need to do some background reading to understand how this works.

Could you explain about other parameters?

Comment: You can access the regex matches through %1, %2, %3 and so on. So if you want to match other params, you could go with a regex like: `(.*)pid=([^&]*)&?(.*)$` and change the rule to %2?%1&%3 but in some cases you'd be left with hanging ampersands or question marks

Comment: I added unnecessary & in the previous comment but can't edit it. Edited the answer to include solution for other parameters.

Comment: Your pattern `^(.*)pid=([^&]*)&?(.*)$` is equivalent to `pid=([^&]*)`

Comment: @JustinIurman Correct me if I'm wrong, but `pid=([^&]*)` won't let me capture parameters after pid. The comment remains valid for the situation where I drop the params though. I corrected my answer.

Comment: If you keep the pattern i gave you, you have to omit the leading `^` and the trailing `$`. This way, it does exactly the same as your initial pattern `^(.*)pid=([^&]*)&?(.*)$`

Comment: I tried it on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ but it doesn't recognize %2 and %3 with your regex.

Comment: I forgot to tell you that my pattern is only available when you don't care about other query parameters but only `pid` value (which make sense, regarding on the pattern i gave you)

Comment: @makhan really grateful for your help but i cannot see how i can apply it to my redirect puzzle. 

For example I have two old urls like this: 
http://tinyurl.com/nh9k4ns (which should redirect here: http://tinyurl.com/o54vbzv) 

and this one 
http://tinyurl.com/nrlzqer (which should go here: http://tinyurl.com/ozcde29)

Comment: Ouch. It seems you have multiple destination URLs. To convert the first url you could use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)pid=([^&]*)&?(.*)$ [NC]` and 
`RewriteRule ^product_page\.php /shop/Art_Prints/Art_Prints/%2?%1%3 [R=301,NE,L,QSA]` but that leaves the problem of trailing A and spaces instead of underscores. Plus you'd need a different rule for each of the categories (I see you have quite a few of them). Have you tried doing the redirection at a later stage, in PHP?

Comment: thanks @makhan. i have got it working - redirecting without the query string. I have to do 100 or so but thats ok. I'm using 
`code`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pid=the%20product%id
RewriteRule ^the_old_page.php? /my/new/url/the_product_id? [R=301,NE,L]`code`

Answer (score 0):

Putting a question mark at the end of the target will clear the query string.

```
RewriteRule ^page\.php /my/new/url/for/Product_Name? [R=301,NE,L]
```

If you find yourself repeating the same pattern many times then consider using `RewriteMap` to specify a program to process the URL.

Comment: Sure looks like it should work. But it doesn't.

This rewite in the same file doing a similar thing does work

    #all old news urls
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=
    RewriteRule ^news\.php$ /news.php? [L,R=301]

I guess there is a conflict elsewhere